# Subnets, IPs and Apps within a LAN

Tags: router, routing, lan, subnet, fios

Im trying to use my fios TV guide app with my network, but my network has been set up for a long time. 
So I have a Fios router, that I cant disable the DHCP server. Nor change its IP address. thats plugged into my Asus router which sits at its own IP address and subnet, ie: Fios :192.168.1.1, Asus 192.168.10.1. all my NAS/printers, ect are fixed IP on that subnet.
The problem is the fios app will not connect to the fios Modem to pull down live tv or guide info while on the Asus Wifi connection. and to avoid muddying up and needlessly switching between wifi, I wanted to see if I could set up the subnet mask or static route to get the app to think its connected to Fios wifi when its really just connected to my asus wifi.

Comment: Is the Fios TV guide you're referring to a separate app or the web page on their web site?

Comment: separate app that has to be connected to the 'lan network' of your 'fios' modem. i assume its a special port but cant find out what it is, and since its getting NAT from my asus, i assume thats why it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unify the two subnets into one, or you will fall into a big mess
of route commands and programs and apps that may not be fully controllable.

If the DHCP function of the Fios cannot be disabled (why?), you should disable
it on the Asus router. You might need to set the Asus router to a static IP address,
and ensure that this address is not included in the range in which the Fios router
is allocating its DHCP addresses.

Comment: actually it was just hidden under 'ip address distribution' didnt look like dhcp to me. Would setting both subnets masks to 255.255.0.0 unify them?

Comment: It doesn't really matter for your internal network that stops at the router. It's usually set to 255.255.255.0 for domestic, unless you have more than 252 devices. The Fios can use any address range it likes, it has no importance as well.

Comment: so its likely less the subnet being x.x.1.x and x.x.10.x and more it being a NAT issue being behind a second router?

Comment: In one unified subnet with mask 255.255.255.0 all IPs are supposed to be the same in the first 3 bytes.

Comment: thats difficult to do as each is acting as a router. hence I cant have its internal and external IP within the same subnet (or at least thats why i think i changed it originally like 10 years ago).

Comment: Do you have two internet connections?

Comment: no, one connection. Fios Modem/router/coax connection to Set top boxes. Gigabit WAN on that side.

Comment: Then why do you need two subnets?

Comment: I have the 2nd router set up as the DHCP server for all of my devices. so it ends up with a public ip on router 1, and that cant be the same as its 'internal' ip for the DHCP server. complicated i know

Comment: the Fios modem/router has to be DHCP for the STB, but the 2nd router has to be dhcp to give the NAS, Printer, ect all their ip, but if I put the 2 on the same .10.x then everything freaks out because in public IP of the router is within the ip range of the internal (.10.x)

Comment: I tried to move the .10.x router to the 1.x subnet but it gave me an ip conflict error. the asus router wont let me have the same IP address pool on both WAN and LAN. .10.1 moved to .11.1 when i tried to do that.

Comment: The asus router might have a configuration parameter for the separation of both sub-networks that you could disable.